# EP800 Thermal printer - Image printing produces invalid characters instead of image

Tags: image, linux-device-driver, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm using printer from *Eurocoin* called **EP800** on Linux. It's similar to [ep802](https://eurocoin.co.uk/product/ep802-tm-thermal-printer-with-smart-bezel/) printer in specifications.

When printing an image, sometimes this happens:

[image: EP800 bug]

A lot of times it prints normal image, but sometimes I get this. Does anyone have any idea why this happens sometimes ?

I didn't provide a code since I'm not looking for programming related bug but more of what could cause this ?

Comment: Some printer vendors and models have undocumented real-time commands for performance testing and problem investigation. If part of the graphic data happens to hit the pattern, a phenomenon like a question may occur. Alternatively, although it does not occur recently, the application sends a command regardless of the fact that the printer's receive buffer is full and a notification to suspend sending to the printer is issued, and the command is not established. It is possible that the behavior is strange. Or, likewise, the application may misconfigure the command to do so.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, may it be due to buffer size of printer ?

Comment: The buffer size is compatible with dot printers and 4Kbytes is mainly documented. But they will actually have larger buffers. The value may not be published.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out ! I didn't managed not to even find this printer on eurocoin.co.uk , probably there isn't everything documented.